# How do I color multiple columns in Cytoscape?

Tags: cytoscape

I'm new to Cytoscape and working on a project for my work. I sorted the nodes by school affiliation, and then I need to color them based on affiliation as well. The issue I'm running into is that when I use discrete mapping to color the nodes I can only color one column.

[image: The way that I have colored the nodes so far.]

The other column that I need to color is called Primary Organization1, but when I switch the column name to that the formatting that I did already disappears. Is there a way to color multiple columns? Or, at the very least color individual nodes? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Well, it depends on what you want to see.  Typically, if you want to color by two columns, you are going to need to split the node in some way in order to see both colors.  In Cytoscape, you could use the built-in charts and graphs to do that.  That will allow you to set up a pie chart with different colors on each side.  Take a look at the tutorial here: https://cytoscape.org/cytoscape-tutorials/protocols/mapping-data/#/8

Alternatively, you could use a very thick border and color the border by Primary Organization1.  That's certainly the easiest way to do it.

-- scooter